# Showing $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}x\mathbb{P}(X>x)=0$ for a nonegative random variable $X$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I'm trying to show that $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}x\mathbb{P}(X>x)=0$ for any nonnegative (integrable) random variable $X$. My idea is to establish this by establishing $\int_{0}^{\infty}x\mathbb{P}(X>x)<\infty$. Letting $F$ denote the cumulative distribution function, I know that
$$
\int_{0}^{c}x\mathbb{P}(X>x)=\int_{0}^{c}x\left(1-F(x)\right)dx
$$
for any positive number $c$. If I can show that the above is bounded and take the limit $c \rightarrow \infty$, the desired result follows. I'm not sure how to proceed, however. I tried IBP and I know that $\mathbb{E}[X\wedge c] = \int_0^c x(1-F(x))dx$, but I don't know how to handle the other terms.

Comment: We need integrability of $X$, for otherwise we have counter-examples like $\mathbb{P}(X> x) = 1/x$ for $x > 1$ (that is, $X$ has the [*Pareto distribution*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_distribution) of shape parameter $1$).

Comment: I agree with you; I mentioned in the question that $X$ is integrable.

Comment: You are right, I am not sure why I missed that parenthesis...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

If $X$ is integrable and nonnegative then $E(X) = \int_0^\infty ydF(y) < \infty$, and

$$xP(X > x) = x\int_x^\infty dF(y) \leqslant \int_x^\infty ydF(y) $$